# Java differences in parsed timestamps are ignored

Tags: java, date-parsing, localtime

In the following examples I succeeded to parse timestams in format yyMMddHHmmss(+-)HHss (a date plus or minus some time shift).

So, when I give two identical timestamps, and a different shift, the result should be different.

For example, let's take the datetime: 190219010000 (19th of February 2019, 01:00 [AM]), we can add 2 hours (the time will be 03:00) or subtract 2 hours (the time will be 23:00 and the date will be 18th of February) - that is, the parsed object should have 4 hours difference.

In the following, running example, the timeshift is ignored. I can write any number and the output is always "19th of February 2019, 01:00".

```
//Input timestamps: "190219010000+0200" "190219010000-0200"
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { //parsing "19th of February 2019, 01:00 [AM]" +- 2hours
    LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("190219010000+0200", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmssx"));
    LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("190219010000-0200", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmssx"));
    System.out.println("190219010000+0200: " +ldt1);
    System.out.println("190219010000-0200: "+ ldt2);
  }
}
```

REAL output: in both cases the output is the same, but the input was different :/

```
190219010000+0200: 2019-02-19T01:00
190219010000-0200: 2019-02-19T01:00
```

Expected output:

```
190219010000+0200: 2019-02-19T03:00
190219010000-0200: 2019-02-18T23:00
```

Maybe I should use something else instead of the x in the pattern? Or a LocalDateTimeFormatter (that doesn't exist) instead of DateTimeFormatter?

Thanks

Comment: `LocalDateTime` doesn't care about the offset. Why not use `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: Simply, LocalDateTime is used everywhere in the project, I know that it doesn't include the offset, but I thougth that it whould be included in the time, before it was removed. It's just removed loosing information, maybe I misunderstood something...

Comment: If you're using `LocalDateTime` to store timestamps everywhere, I'd suggest that's what should change. `Instant` is generally a more appropriate type for timestamps, as that's unambiguous about exactly which instant is being represented. `LocalDateTime` is inherently and deliberately ambiguous about that - the same `LocalDateTime` means different things depending on where "local" is.

Comment: That's very interesting, I think I should plan some changes, but when i started the project I already found it as it is. It's something that could be discussed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you have misunderstood. In your code `LocalDateTime.parse` behaves as designed.

You are correct that `190219010000+0200` is an unambiguous point in time (given that we know that the format is `yyMMddHHmmssx`). `LocalDateTime.parse` gives you the local date and time that is in the string. In other words, the local date and time at offset +02:00.

If you want a conversion, for example to UTC, you need to specify that explicitly:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("190219010000+0200", 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmssx"));
    LocalDateTime ldt1 = odt1.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime();

    System.out.println("190219010000+0200: " + ldt1);
```

Now the output is the one you expected. Almost.

> 190219010000+0200: 2019-02-18T23:00

As Jon Skeet already said `+0200` generally means that a UTC offset of +02:00 *has been* applied to the date and time. So 01:00 at +02:00 is the same point in time as 23:00 on the previous day in UTC (if your strings are very special and apply the opposite convention for offsets, that can be solved too, but requires a little more hand work).

Comment: Exactly what i needed. A LocalTime that includes the offset without loosing information.

Answer (score 4):

> In the following, running example, the timeshift is ignored.

Yes, that doesn't surprise me. You're parsing the *local* value being represented - that's the meaning of a `LocalDateTime`.

A string of "190219010000+0200" means "February 19th 2019, 1am local time, with a UTC offset of 2 hours". The local time of that *is* 2019-02-19T01:00. If you don't want to get the local date and time represented by your text, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type to use.

It looks like what you *really* want is the UTC time, in which case you should parse the value as an `OffsetDateTime` and then probably convert to an `Instant`. I'd expect the results to be in the opposite direction from you though: +0200 generally means "the local time is two hours *ahead* of UTC", making the UTC value 11pm the previous day - it's not the amount to add to *get* to UTC.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then. I thought that the string "190219010000+0200" means "February 19th 2019, 1am, with a UTC offset of +2 hours" compared with local time (that is 19th february 2019, 3 am in my local time).

Comment: @fresko: No, 3am in local time would be represented as "190219030000+0200" - at least in every system I've worked with. That's how ISO-8601 works.

Answer (score 2):

**LocalDateTime** has no timezone information and does not store or represent a time-zone. Hence in your case, both **ldt1** and **ldt2** represents the same local time.